# Возможно ли загрузить библиотеку d3js on scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap, d3.js

Есть страница, фреймворк bootstrap 4.5 на которой графики, реализованные на d3js находятся глубоко внизу страницы (страница длинная).
Существует ли возможность подгружать библиотеку отрисовки по мере необходимости? В идеале по событию scroll: тоесть при достижении какой-то части документа догружать d3js для отрисовки?

Comment: Да, можно. Что вы пробовали, что не получилось?

Comment: Я не уверен что знаю, как правильно это организовать в принципе

Comment: @Silver почитайте [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API), [ScrollTrigger](https://greensock.com/docs/v3/Plugins/ScrollTrigger), [ScrollMagic](https://scrollmagic.io/) Вариантов много. И по старинке событие `addEventListener('scroll', ...)`

Comment: @Silver на каждую задачу в js есть 2-4 решения, я бы сказал трудно сказать `как правильно` для любой даже элементарной задачи, так как это своеобразная демагогия в большинстве случаев получается.